# Why is this question valid?

Tags: discussion, off-topic, declined-flags

I was wondering if somebody can explain why a general question about WYSIWYG editors is considered a valid question at StackOverflow.  I flagged it but my flag was labeled "invalid".

[This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6552536/looking-for-a-css-html-drag-and-drop-editor)

The OP is simply looking for a Drag & Drop WYSIWYG editor so he doesn't have to do any programming.  <s>I thought this type of thing is what the Webmasters forum was for.</s>

**EDIT:**  I only mentioned the Webmaster's forum because there are a bunch of similar questions there.  However, I honestly do not remember exactly how I wrote my flag... I may or may not have suggested the Webmaster forum or any other forum.  Despite whether or not my flag contained a suggested location, shouldn't a mod have taken the most appropriate action?

**EDIT 2:**  From my own flag weight page:  *off topic; belongs on Webmasters*

Comment: It's absolutely **not** on-topic on Webmasters. If you flagged it as such, the flag was rightly marked invalid. However, I agree with you that the question is not valid on SO and should be closed. Voted to close as off-topic

Comment: @Pekka's serious account:  Okay, so it doesn't belong on Webmaster's either... even though I saw a million similar questions at Webmasters.  My flag was invalid because I might have suggested the wrong place?  Shouldn't a mod take the most correct action despite that fact?

Comment: What did you flag it as? - anyway, mods are just people too, and they have to deal with hundreds of flags. It is possible they made the wrong decision. I'll flag it too.

Comment: @Pekka's serious account:  Of course, I totally understand the hard work they do.  Since I'm now noticing lots of WYSIWYG Editor questions in a couple different forums, I figured I'd ask you all here.  It was from earlier today so I'm not 100% positive if I suggested the Webmaster forum, another forum, or just _'does not belong here'_.  BTW- where would something like this belong?

Comment: I don't think it belongs anywhere, except maybe on Superuser. It's definitely off-topic. It's going to get closed sooner or later

Comment: Although I was opposed to it, the "see which flags were valid/invalid" feature was implemented... and I'm cautiously optimistic that it *will* prove useful in helping users learn. Gosh, I sure hope this doesn't end up making me more cynical.

Comment: @Shog9:  We have to learn how to do this properly or nobody will want to stick their neck out.  On marginal questions, I don't think twice about getting an occasional "invalid"... I think I learned something.  On this question, it seemed clear that it didn't belong there so I had to figure out my flag error.

Comment: @Shog9 and @Pekka:  Now I see here too... I may have forgotten what I did earlier but my flag weight page does not lie:  _"off topic; belongs on Webmasters"_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Despite whether or not my flag contained a suggested location, shouldn't a mod have taken the most appropriate action?

You suggested an inappropriate action. So your flag was marked invalid, and nothing was done.

Yes, a moderator could have evaluated the question, determined the proper course of action, and dealt with it. But you didn't suggest a proper course of action, so you didn't really help this to happen, and I'm not overly surprised that it didn't. FWIW, several other people posted similarly unhelpful flags.

For future reference, if you don't *know* where a question belongs, but feel it's off-topic... then just flag it as off-topic. Once you gain the necessary reputation, we hope you'll skip flagging and *vote* to close it - and by that time, you'll hopefully have learned how to differentiate between worthwhile questions that can benefit from being migrated, and questions that don't belong anywhere.

FWIW, the question was a duplicate of a much earlier question, which I personally feel is at least borderline on-topic as a programming-tools question. If you dispute this, flag it...